# Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a problem with Laravel . after restart my system, My project will not run !!!

I run with `php artisan serv` , but I have below messages in console :

```
[Tue Jul  3 14:31:35 2018] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /laravel-projects/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php on line 122
[Tue Jul  3 14:31:35 2018] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /laravel-projects/blog/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php on line 46
[Tue Jul  3 14:31:38 2018] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /laravel-projects/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php on line 122
[Tue Jul  3 14:31:39 2018] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /laravel-projects/blog/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php on line 46
[Tue Jul  3 14:31:39 2018] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /laravel-projects/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php on line 122
```

Before the system was restored, the project was well implemented !!

Comment: This means you need to also update your php.ini memory_limit directive.Try put in your php.ini:`memory_limit=1024M`. test please

Comment: I made changes, but it did not work !!!

Comment: after change , restart apache and test again

Comment: Yeeees. very Thanks

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This means you need to also update your **php.ini** `memory_limit` directive.

Try put in your php.ini :

**memory_limit=1024M** and restart **apache** :

`sudo systemctl restart httpd.service`

Answer (score 16):

Change in `php.ini` which is there inside `apache2` folder

```
memory_limit=1024M

restart apache2
```

you can even check which php ini config is using by:

```
php -i | grep "php.ini"
```

Comment: Thanks . There is no such file in the following path :

/opt/lampp/apache2

Comment: check here /etc/php/5.6/apache2/php.ini

Answer (score 12):

This problem occurs when an application uses more memory than PHP allows. thanks to PHP's relatively conservative default memory settings. you can fix this issue by change memory_limit size in your php.ini

**memory_limit= Replace your size(1024M /2048M/etc)**
change and save it, then restart the services.

- In Windows, you can find "C:\wamp64\bin\php\php_version\php.ini" then restart your service.
- In Ubuntu, you can find "/etc/php/php_version/apache2/php.ini" then run
  `sudo systemctl restart apache2` for restart apache.

You can simply increase the memory limit programmatically early on in your code, before your process runs out of memory. If you do it this way, you can give PHP extra memory only when that piece of code gets called rather than increasing the memory limit for all PHP processes.

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');
```

Answer (score 6):

```
php -d memory_limit=1024M artisan serv
```

If you don't want to change global php.ini settings or you dont have access to change it. Then this workaround will work to get things done.

Make sure you are using correct php version, as sometimes php-cli may have set to some other version, that might cause some other issues.